Download a PDF using Selenium in Python
I'm trying to download the following PDF from a browser's PDF viewer by clicking the download button.

I tried the following code using ID, CSS_SELECTOR, and XPATH locators, but it seems not to be working.
What could be the issue? Can someone help me with this?
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


download_url = "https://www.npci.org.in/PDF/nach/circular/2015-16/Circular-No.135.pdf"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

driver.get(download_url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#icon')))
driver.find_element(By.ID, '#icon').click()

time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()


Does this answer your question? Downloading a PDF using Selenium, Chrome and Python

@BarrythePlatipus can you please provide a working example? I tried the given solution with different variations, but sometimes it downloads the file, and all times I get "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException". When I add "options.add_argument("--headless=new")", it does not work. How can I properly download this without breaking the code? How can wait until the file is fully downloaded?

The fact that sometimes it downloads the file should tell you the solution is working. That particular website might not work all the time, beside being geo-restricted. Maybe the website has antiscrape restrictions in place for headless browsers.

@BarrythePlatipus Well if you quit the browser (or navigate away from the page) before the download completes, it will kill the download. That could be the reason for the intermittent issues.

Is your primary goal to learn how to download the file using Selenium or simply to download the file itself? If you only need to download the PDF file, I recommend using a simpler method, such as the requests library
example:
import requests

url = 'https://www.npci.org.in/PDF/nach/circular/2015-16/Circular-No.135.pdf'
path = 'sample.pdf'

response = requests.get(url)

with open(path, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)


With this website, this solution does not work unless I sends cookie with the requests headers

When you initiate a download, you need to keep the webdriver running until the download has completed. However, there is no built-in method in Selenium to wait for the download to be completed.
The following script will download the PDF file to a provided folder path. This is achieved by opening Chrome's Download Manager and monitoring the status of the last download.
When the status is complete, the driver waits another couple of seconds to ensure the downloaded file was renamed.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def download_pdf_to_custom_path(download_url, download_folder):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",  {
        "download.default_directory": download_folder,
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
        }
    )

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options)
    driver.get(download_url)
    # Give some time for the download to begin
    time.sleep(5)
    # Open the Downloads Manager window
    driver.get("chrome://downloads")
    # Execute JavaScript code to get list of downloads
    download_items_script = "return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.getElementById('downloadsList').items;"
    items = driver.execute_script(download_items_script)
    # Most recent download is the first item in the list
    # Each downloaded item has an attribute, `state`, that we can poll.
    # Loop the JavaScript code block while the download state is in progress.
    while items[0]["state"] == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        items = driver.execute_script(download_items_script)

    # The `state` will change to 2 when the download is complete
    if items[0]["state"] == 2:
        # Give the browser some time to rename the downloaded file
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        # The download did not complete successfully.
        print(f"Something went wrong. {items[0]['state']}")

    driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pathlib import Path
    download_url = "https://www.npci.org.in/PDF/nach/circular/2015-16/Circular-No.135.pdf"
    folder = str(Path(__file__).parent)
    download_pdf_to_custom_path(download_url, folder)


I gotta admit... I was skeptical of this but it works. This is nice. Is this something you figured out or did you find it somewhere (polling the state of the item on the downloads page)?

With a little googling, I added to your JS so that you don't have to rely on using the first item on the page which means you don't have to sleep for 5s... some smaller files will be done almost instantly so less waiting is a good thing (tm).
document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.getElementById('downloadsList').items.find((element) => element["url"].url.includes("Circular-No.135.pdf"))

I was able to successfully replace the time.sleep(5) with WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form"))) which should provide more consistent results and be a littler faster.

Just a heads up to OP, this won't work with --headless because Chrome can't render a PDF without a display (or a virtual-display). FireFox, on the other hand, does that out of the box, i.e. download PDFs in headless mode using Selenium.

@JeffC The idea of monitoring the status of the download manager came to me some time ago. Inspecting the downloads manager page with the dev tools aided the creation of the JavaScript code. My previous method had been to monitor the file system for the file to appear. The reason I used time.sleep(5) was that the original computer that ran the selenium script was relatively old and quite slow. Modern day hardware and high speed internet connections would probably negate the need for it, but years later the original code is still running on that old machine.

if you are just looking to download a Single file, your best bet is to use the request library. If you are looking to download any file possible, then you will have to become creative.
1 - Downloading a Single File:
import requests

pdf_url = 'https://www.npci.org.in/PDF/nach/circular/2015-16/Circular-No.135.pdf'
path = 'sample.pdf'

response = requests.get(pdf_url)

with open(path, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)

2 - Downloading any File
With this, there are two approaches you could use: using the sys library to rad your download folder directly or using selenium and js to inspect the chrome download manager.
2a Reading your download path:

With this method, you first read all the files in your system download path wondering them by the date modified, so that you can get the last file that was downloaded.
Next, execute your selenium download function and perform a sleep time(the duration will depend on what you need)
Next, you check you download path again to get the new file that was downloaded

Note you could use a loop to keep checking the download folder to keep checking the downloaded folder to ensure that the file has been downloaded and is readable(with try statements of course)
2b Using the home download inspector.:
First, you have to spend some time with your Chrome browser. Download any large file on the internet and throttle your download speed if needed. use the chrome inspector to inspect the download element to know when the progress bar is available on an item which means that the item is downloading.
Next, write your selenium code to:
-Download the file
-Visit the download manager page, use Selenium to keep checking the presence of the progress bar on the target element of the new download
